# Define package-wide default imports

Tags: scala

How can I define package-wide default imports? I want to define a package `p` such that

```
import p._
```

is equivalent to

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the pattern used in [scala/package.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/package.scala) to make some of the standard collection available without imports. It involves a `package object` with a `type` and a `val` for each import:

```
package object p {
  type Try[A] = scala.util.Try[A]
  val Try = scala.util.Try
  type Queue[A] = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[A]
  val Queue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue
}
```